How to correct a one-day offset in a calendar heatmap in Superset?
I am working on Superset and I am trying to create a calendar heatmap. I've encountered a problem: I want to display the number of occurrences I have per day. I perform a count with a daily granularity. The count number is correct, but the display is offset by one day compared to what is in the table. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Interesting.  Can you share more detail?  Maybe the SQL query behind the chart and/or a screenshot of the results?  If you believe this is a bug you could open a reproducible example in the Superset GitHub issues tracker.
